# Getting error: This command is no longer functional, please use `puppetserver ca` instead

Tags: puppet, ubuntu-18.04

When running command to attaching certification to puppet master --> agent

```
sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet cert list
```

I am getting message as:

> This command is no longer functional, please use `puppetserver ca`
>   instead.

Comment: Why don't you use `puppetserver ca list` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `puppet cert list`, please use

```
puppetserver ca list
```

Answer (score 0):

puppet cert has been deprecated. When using puppetserver as the master, to list all the certificates

`puppetserver ca list --all` has to be used.

It is also convenient to add a Simulink at /usr/local/sbin/puppetserver, assuming this path is in your system path. This way the whole path to the binary need not have to be typed.

`ln -s /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppetserver /usr/local/sbin/puppetserver`

Comment: Not working: 
Fatal error when running action 'list'
  Error: Failed connecting to https://puppet:8140/puppet-ca/v1/certificate_statuses/any_key
  Root cause: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain)